# Java classpath issue with external jars

Tags: java, makefile

I am having issues compiling external jars along with my source code. My .java files and the external jar reside in the same directory. Here is my makefile:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac -cp ${CLASSPATH}
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSPATH = *.jar 

CLASSES = \
        AESCBC.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:
        $(RM) *.class
```

The compilation succeeds. However, when I run`java AESCBC`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify your dependencies when running your class. Assuming your class is not compiled into a JAR you will run it like so:

java -cp [PLACE YOUR DEPENDENCIES HERE] AESCBC